# Is there an alternative to Samba when it comes to sharing folders between Linux and Windows systems?

Tags: samba, network-share, file-sharing, server-message-block

Let's assume I have two workstations. Workstation A is a Debian GNU/Linux based system with a bandwidth of approximately 100 MBit/s (up). Workstation B is a Microsoft Windows 7 based system with a bandwidth of approximately 15 MBit/s (down). Now I'd like to edit and share files between them, without having to rely on 3rd party tools/clients. For this I've been using SMB/CIFS (Samba) lately, but the performance I get isn't exactly satisfying. I expected to get roughly the same throughput I get when using (Win)SCP to download files from Worstation A to Workstation B -using SMB/CIFS I got round about 50% to 60% of that. I've been heavily editing the smb.conf (mainly socket options like SO_RCVBUF and SO_SNDBUF) accordingly to various sites on the world wide web to achieve a better throughput, but unfortunately all the tuning and tweaking had the opposite effect slowing down everything even worse.

Comment: Sorry - this seems like something few people will ever want to do.  If you need consistent throughput for downloading files to both workstations then you probably need to set up a server in the middle, or stick with storing your files on Workstation A.  It seems like you might spend more time trying to make this work perfectly than you will ever save in download speed.

Comment: May FTP protocol work on this situation?

Comment: @ghm1014 Last time I tried out the FTP client built-in Windows Explorer it wouldn't let me modify files without copying the file to my local storage and uploading it again after I finished editing. Has that changed? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You may keep using samba, store your files on the samba share and configure your windows machine to use offline files.

Offline files will keep your data in sync and use BITS to transfer the modified files in the background.

Comment: Will it work so nice? Have you ever tryed it? I'm really interested in a real case implementation of that option. Thanks